# without DBA supreme authority, how to acquire lock table information of database?

Tags: database-design, db2, database-administration

Without DBA supreme authority， how to acquire lock table information of database?

Execute:

```
select * from sysibmadm.snaplock
```

appear:

```
[SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -1092, SQL State:      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "DBA supreme authority", whatever that means, but you do need the SYSMON authority to access any monitoring information, including that about locks. There is no way around it.

Comment: Execute:update dbm cfg using sysmon_group dba ,but appear:SQL5001N "HSISS30", does not change the database manager configuration file permissions

Comment: But of course, if you were a SYSADM this would not be a problem in the first place, would it.